# WebClient Can't download Page WP8

Tags: webclient

I have some problem with this Code

```
        Webclient wc= new WebClient();
       wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new        DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://tv.csmtalk.vn"));


void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Result);
}
```

Some site such as `"google.com.vn"` the result is nice. But when i use the site `"tv.csmtalk.vn"` the result is nothing. but viewsource in Chrome , firefox, IE is ok.

anyone can help me?

Comment: tired of give a question in any forum but noone answer me?

Comment: did you try the same url in emularor browser?

Comment: I had tried to. do you know which is problem?